# Bulk Insert Type Mismatch or Invalid Character

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, ssms, bulkinsert

I have searched through numerous bulk insert type mismatch SO questions but have yet to find one that addresses my exact issue. I am bulk inserting a CSV into a local SSMS datbase, however I keep receiving the error:

```
' (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, 
   column 4 (DayNumber) '
```

This error repeats until SSMS reaches the maximum number of errors. I have seen this error before and have always been able to work through it. Additionally, i have tried all the standard fixes listed on SO but have not had any luck. Three things stick out to me about this particular error that may lead to someone being able to assist me:

```
1) DayNumber is actually column 5 in the underlying CSV, not column 4
2) The DayNumber column simply has numeric values, I even with through row 
   by row to ensure there were no irregular characters contained in the 
   column
3) I have tried bulk inserting the CSV with this column set as a varchar, 
   int, numeric, and float - all of which produce the same error
```

Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated as this is holding up the entire project. Also, I am successfully bulk inserting 2 differnt CSV files into the same query. These CSV files are stored in the exact same folder as the file that is causing the error.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

SAMPLE DATA BELOW:

Sample CSV Data:

```
Country     Region       Month     Date       DayNumber  Location
USA         California   January   8/17/2016    48       USA
England     London       March     6/30/2017    91       England
USA         Wyoming      November  3/31/2017    90       USA
Canada      Alberta      January   12/31/2016   92       Canada
England     Manchester   February  9/30/2016    92       England
New Zealand Auckland     July      6/30/2016    91       New Zealand
USA         New York     December  3/31/2016    91       USA
Canada      Ontario      April     12/31/2015   92       Canada
USA         New York     September 9/30/2015    92       USA
Australia   Queensland   January   6/30/2015    91       Australia
Australia   Sydey        March     3/31/2015    90       Australia
USA         San Diego    February  12/31/2014   92       USA
Canada      Quebec       October   9/30/2014    92       Canada
USA         Florida      August    6/30/2014    91       USA
```

Sample Bulk insert statement:

```
Create Table Table_A
 (
   [Country] varchar(max),
   [Region] varchar(max),
   [Month] varchar(max),
   [Date] varchar(max),
   [DayNumber] varchar(max),
   [Location] varchar(max),
                                )
  GO

BULK INSERT
Table_A
FROM 'C:\Path\CSV.csv'
WITH

(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2
);
```

Comment: Can you provide your csv file, and can you provide the bulk insert query

Comment: @MBurnham I added sample data and bulk insert statement to the original question

Comment: @MBurnham thanks a ton for your assistance

Comment: CVS sample provided doesn't include any comma as field terminator, it looks like a \t and row terminator can also be \n\r

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you format the data like this it will work. Turn on 'show all chars' in note pad++ and make sure there are no hidden characters between fields (only at the end of each record).